# Using multiple enum lists to populate a 2nd dropdown based on the values of the first dropdown

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I'm struggling with what seems like it should be really easy thing to do.

Assume I have two drop downs Country and City.

For a user of the system I want them to select their address using these drop downs.

I was thinking of Creating an Enum for all the countries, and then a list of enums for all the countries. And then using a javascript OnChange for the first drop down to switch the second dropdown so I'd have the right list of cities for each country. (UKCities, IndiaCities, USCities etc...)

But this started to feel like a bad idea when I considered the User View model, what type would I use for the city for a user?  After doing some googling I found this article: [Using Drop Down Lists with enums](https://nimblegecko.com/aspnetmvc-dropdowns-with-enums/) and I think I could use the generics part of this to do what I want.  But I can't help the feeling that I'm way over complicating the issue.

Any thoughts/examples of how to do this in a more straight forward manner.

Comment: Do you have a hard requirement on using enums?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be an enum. but it does seem to be what's currently used in the system to populate dropdowns. If it wasn't Country and City but was say but a smaller list, unlikely to change what would you suggest

Comment: You want cascading dropdownlists. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example. And enums are not appropriate in your case

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks Stephen, I've used this to create what I need, if you want to enter an answer for this I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a hard requirement on using enums?

Without knowing more about your code, arquitecture or what tecnologies you are using, I can only give you a generic advice:

This seems like something that should be fetched from a database, and not be hardcoded in an enum.

This has a lot of advantages, as it is more dynamic and easier to maintain (you won't need to recompile your app in order to add or remove a country/city), and you could enforce data integrity using a relationship constaint between the User and Country/City tables.

You can further read about this discussion in other [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298472/is-it-wasteful-to-create-a-new-database-table-instead-of-using-enum-data-type) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680744/when-to-use-an-enum-or-a-small-table-in-a-relational-database) questions (although some opinions differ, so you should make your own judgement about this topic).

Comment: No it doesn't have to be an enum.  but it does seem to be what's currently used in the system to populate dropdowns.  If it wasn't Country and City but was say but a smaller list, unlikely to change what would you suggest

Comment: @AidanO I would actualy almost never suggest an enum unless, if the values change, I also need to change my code (i.e.: when my code needs to make a decision based on when the value is X or Y, AND, that these values will almost never change.
But there are countless other posts on SO and SE about [this problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298472/is-it-wasteful-to-create-a-new-database-table-instead-of-using-enum-data-type)