# Foreign key reference as enum?

Tags: laravel, database-design

I'm creating a Favorites table in Laravel, where the favorited item can be either another user, a user group, or a report. This list may grow in the future, allowing users to favorite more things.

Here is where I'm at with the database migratoin:

```php
Schema::create('favorites'. function (Blueprint $table) {
  $types = ['user', 'user_group', 'report'];
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->foreign->('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
  $table->enum('item_type', $types);
  $table->foreign->('item_id')->references('id')->on($types)
```

Would this work properly? If not, how can I encode favorites of different types? Thanks!

Comment: user_group and report are models?

Comment: Is there any problem are you facing while implementing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680744/when-to-use-an-enum-or-a-small-table-in-a-relational-database) to see whether you should use enum in your case.

If I was you I will probably either create 3 boolean values to check the types:

```
$table->boolean('is_user')->default(0);
$table->boolean('is_user_group')->default(0);
$table->boolean('is_report')->default(0);
```

Or just use normal strings:

```
$table->string('item_type');
```

For the input validations, I'll do it in the controller, to avoid any unnecessary errors caused by `enum` .